# RPi 2B - Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS fails to boot, but Raspbian works. How to further troubleshoot?

Tags: pi-2, boot-issues

I'm trying to flash Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS using the Raspberry Pi Imager for my Raspberry Pi 2B, but boot fails on the blended colors / rainbow screen and blinks the green LED seven times.

As I understand it, this means that the kernel was not found, but I checked the partition and it's there.

**What I have tried so far**

- Different chargers
- Different cables
- Tried the SD card in a Pi 3B (boots)
- Flashing Raspbian (Pi 2 boots with it)

Can you please point me into a direction on how to troubleshoot this further? It would be most awesome if someone owning a 2B could try flashing Ubuntu Server 20.04 as well to exclude whether their image file is broken for the by now relatively ancient 2B.

Comment: What EXACTLY did you download? WHY?

Comment: @Milliways Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 LTS (RPi 2/3/4/400) (Flashed to SD card via the Raspberry Pi Imager from AUR https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rpi-imager/). For the why, I want to use it as print-server and need to run a specific x86 printer driver via emulation.

Comment: Did you pick the release for ARM?

Comment: @Swedgin Its says RPi 2 in the name, so I suppose that means yes and it should be compatible :)